# Embedded Kafka assigns partitions after the application is started

Tags: spring-kafka

My application listens the ApplicationReadyEvent.class and then subscribes via consumer with custom ConsumerRebalanceListener

```
val assigned = new AtomicReference<Collection<TopicPartition>>();
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topicName"), new ConsumerRebalanseListener () {
  public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
    //do nothing
  }

  public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartitions> partitions) {
    assigned.set(partitions);
  }
}
while(assigned.get() == null){
  consumer.pull(10000);
}
```

In live Kafka everything works correct, partitions become assigned after some time, but when I run the unit test with EmbeddedKafka, method onPartitionsAssigned is never called.

Seems that the ApplicationReadyEvent.class fires earlier than any partitions is assigned.

Tried to assign partitions before application is ready.

Comment: Any chances to see some simple project from you to let us to reproduce on our side and play with?